a group isomorphic to $O(2N)$
Consider the set of $2N\times 2N $ complex matrices $T$ satisfying the conditions
$$TT^\dagger = I_{2N}$$
and ($^*$ means taking the complex conjugate)
$$ T^* = \gamma T \gamma ,$$
where $\gamma $ is the $2N\times 2N $ matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & I_N\\
I_N & 0
\end{pmatrix} .$$
It is stated without proof that such $T$ form a group isomporphic to the orthogonal group $O(2N )$. It is easy to prove that they form a group, but how to prove that the group is isomorphic to $O(2N)$, the real orthogonal group? This is a fundamental fact in quantum mechanics of fermions, actually.

Hello. What is your definition of $O(2N)$ ?

@NaNoS   the standard orthogonal group.

please give a proper definition, the standard orthogonal group is made of real matrices, is it the case for your matrices $T$? Also notice that $\gamma = \gamma^{-1}$

@julio_es_sui_glace $T$ are complex.

As julio_es_sui_glace said, what is denoted by $O(2N)$ is the group of real matrices that are orthogonal, i.e. $M \in O(2N) \Longleftrightarrow$ M is invertible and $M^T = M^{-1}$. If you are working with complex matrices, the analogous notion is the unitary group $U(2N)$ consisting of unitary matrices. Your question is not clear at all. Please add details to your initial question. For example : "It is stated without proof that such $T$ form a group isomporphic to the orthogonal group $O(2N)$.", where did you read this ?

The point is that you can write $\alpha(\alpha^*)^{-1}=\gamma$ with some $\alpha\in U_{2N}(\mathbb{C})$. Just take $\alpha$ which acts as $1$ on the eigenspace $E_1(\gamma)$ and as $i$ on $E_{-1}(\gamma)$.
Then the map $T\mapsto \alpha^{-1} T\alpha$ is an isomorphism from your group to $O(2N)$.
Indeed, if $T\in M_{2N}(\mathbb{C})$, then the condition $T^*=\gamma^{-1} T\gamma$ can be rewritten as $(\alpha^{-1} T\alpha)^* = \alpha^{-1} T\alpha$, ie $\alpha^{-1} T\alpha\in M_{2N}(\mathbb{R})$, and then the condition $TT^\dagger=I_{2n}$ just says that $\alpha^{-1} T\alpha$ is orthogonal.
